# Shrinking a room with Tzaraas to less than 4x4 Amos

Tags: halacha-theory, tzaraas-negaim, contemporary-halacha

May one shrink a room and then manually scrape off questionable Tzaraas (not yet paskened by a Kohen) found there?

Suppose for example, a whole house or one of the rooms is 5x5 Amos, but has a retractable wall that can shrink it to 3x5 Amos. Being that a house less than 4x4 Amos is not subject to the laws of Tzaraas found (as well as a myriad of other Halachic requirements, like having a fence on the roof, Mezuzah, etc., as learned out from [Sukkah 3a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.3a.13)), can someone then remove the questionable white material and then expand their wall, thus completely avoiding a Kohen to render it as Tzaraas?

If indeed one may do such a thing, then what's there to stop someone from purchasing a small house in a walled city, expanding it within the first year, and then perpetually preventing the first owner from buying it back? Or if one creates an excuse not to go to war by simply moving the walls outward?

Here's a bird's eye view of a room being retracted:

[image: Shrinking a room down to avoid Tzaraas.]

Comment: I presume that the *issur* of *hishamer be'nega ha'tzaraas* - not to remove *tzaraas* - applies to pre-*paskened* *tzaraas* also?

Comment: But it's not yet Halachically Tzara'as!

Comment: Is there any reason to think this situation is remotely common? If not, then "what's to stop someone" isn't that compelling a question.

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%94:%D7%9C%D7%90_%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%A9_%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%99_%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%A2%D7%AA בין קדם שיראה הכהן הנגע, בין תוך ימי הסגר, בין תוך ימי החלט, או אפילו אחר הפטור בכל זה עובר בלא תעשה וחייב מלקות

Comment: Presumably the *halacha* of shrinking the size of a room is similar to the *halacha* of shrinking the height of a *succah*. So that if you intend to be permanently *mevatel* the material you add to shrink the size of the room then this words, otherwise it makes no difference.

Comment: Is the retractable wall considered a wall at all for this purpose? And I would guess (just a guess) that this would be the same as for mezuza, so there should be poskim on this.